# Spring Data and native query with like statement

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following repository definition:

```
public interface InstructionRepository extends JpaRepositoryWithSpecification<Instruction> {

    String FIND_INSTRUCTIONS_BY_TRACKING_ID_QUERY =
            "SELECT * FROM instruction i WHERE i.invoice_documents_trackings like '%:trackingId%'";

    @Query(value = FIND_INSTRUCTIONS_BY_TRACKING_ID_QUERY, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Instruction> findByFileTrackingsContaining(@Param("trackingId") String trackingId);
}
```

The reason why I use native query here is because `invoice_documents_trackings` column represents a map serialized to json string. So basically I want to find all instructions that have particular `trackingId` stored in the `invoice_documents_trackings` map.

When I execute the method I always get 0 results despite the fact that If I execute the same query manually I get expected results.

I also tried to change the query so that it looks like:

```
String FIND_INSTRUCTIONS_BY_TRACKING_ID_QUERY =
        "SELECT * FROM instruction i WHERE i.invoice_documents_trackings like %:trackingId%"
```

And this does not work either.

Would really appreciate any help, than

Comment: You can enable Hibernate logging to see which query is being run, that will give some idea why this is not working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is the way you're using `%`

```
String FIND_INSTRUCTIONS_BY_TRACKING_ID_QUERY =
        "SELECT * FROM instruction i WHERE i.invoice_documents_trackings like CONCAT('%', :trackingId, '%')"
```